# Django admin inline instances only if they exist

Tags: django, django-admin, inline-formset

After the "Area Tecnici" formset, there are only inline instances, but some of them are empty. How can I avoid displaying empty heads? I just want to inline a modelAdmin inline instance if it has some instances

(e.g. "S.L. Formazioni" and "HACCP" have some instances, but "S.L. Valutazioni" and "Prestazioni & Servizi" don't, so I don't want to inline "S.L. Valutazioni" and "Prestazioni & Servizi")

[Click here to see the screenshot](https://imageshack.com/i/kmHTELYPp)

Answer (score 2):

You should override `ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines`.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [MyInline, SomeOtherInline]

    def get_formsets_with_inlines(self, request, obj=None):
        for inline in self.get_inline_instances(request, obj):
            # FILTER THE INLINE FORMSET TO YIELD HERE 
            # For example, given obj.related_instances value
            if obj is not None and obj.related_instances.count() > 0:
                yield inline.get_formset(request, obj), inline
```

[See django doc here.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets_with_inlines)

Comment: How can I check if a inline modelAdmin has some instances? Sorry I'm very noob :(

EDIT: I'm using Django 1.5.5, so it doesn't support this method

Comment: For django 1.5, you can override get_formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_formsets

Comment: To check if your inlineAdmin is empty, you could try this (not tested): `if inline.get_queryset().count() > 0`